# How to write data into table after hibernate @EntityListener action using Camel JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, apache-camel

I am inserting data into SQL Server table. During insert I have need to check if any existing row is updating then update another table writing which column is updated. For ex:
Table1: New row inserted A1 and row updated A2
Table2: two rows should be created

```
<Old Value> <New Value> <Unique Key>
""            A1              PK1    --for insert
"Dummy Val"   A2              PK2    --for update
```

I am using Apache-camel, hibernate, jpa

Main table in which inserting data:

```
@Entity(name = "tableName")
@EntityListeners(value = updateEntityListener.class)
public class ExampleTable{

    @Column(name = "col1")
    private int col1;
    //getter setter
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "data";
    }
```

Listener

```
import javax.persistence.PostLoad;
import javax.persistence.PostPersist;
import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;

public class updateEntityListener{
    private String preUpdate = "";
    private String postUpdate = "";

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist(final ExampleTable ex) {
//Insert data in another table
        System.out.println("Row inserted");
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void postUpdate(final ExampleTable ex) {
        postUpdate = ex.toString();
        if (!preUpdate.equals(postUpdate)) {
            System.out.println("Row Updated");
            // Insert in new table, compare from postLoad
        }
    }
    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad(final ExampleTable ex) {
        preUpdate = ex.toString();
    }
}
```

camel Builder(Java DSL)

```
from("timer:invoke?repeatCount=1")
        .log("Processing ${id}")
        .toD("https4://URL")
        .inheritErrorHandler(true)
        .unmarshal()
        .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .split(body())
        .parallelProcessing()
        .process(new MyProcessor())
        .to("jpa:ExampleTable")
```

I need to write data into table2 but not sure where in code and how to write. Any help is appreciated. If this question is already asked please direct me to that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution, sharing so that others can use if stuck in similar scenario.

Created column for second table in entity

```
@Entity(name = "tableName")
@EntityListeners(value = updateEntityListener.class)
public class ExampleTable{

    @Column(name = "col1")
    private int col1;
    @Transient
    private List<Table2> auditInfo = new ArrayList<Table2>();
    //getter setter
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "data";
    }
```

Listener changes:

```
import javax.persistence.PostLoad;
import javax.persistence.PostPersist;
import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;

public class updateEntityListener{
    private String preUpdate = "";
    private String postUpdate = "";

    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist(final ExampleTable ex) {
//Insert data in another table
ex.setAuditInfo(new Object()); //Actual object instead of new Object()
        System.out.println("Row inserted");
    }

    @PostUpdate
    public void postUpdate(final ExampleTable ex) {
        postUpdate = ex.toString();
        if (!preUpdate.equals(postUpdate)) {
            System.out.println("Row Updated");
            // Insert in new table, compare from postLoad
            ex.setAuditInfo(new Object()); 
        }
    }
    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad(final ExampleTable ex) {
        preUpdate = ex.toString();
    }
}
```

Finally builder changes:

```
from("timer:invoke?repeatCount=1")
        .log("Processing ${id}")
        .toD("https4://URL")
        .inheritErrorHandler(true)
        .unmarshal()
        .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .split(body())
        .parallelProcessing()
        .process(new MyProcessor())
        .to("jpa:ExampleTable")
        .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                    List<Table2> info= ((ExampleTable) arg0.getIn().getBody()).getAuditInfo();
                    if (null != info&& info.size() > 0) {
                        arg0.getIn().setBody(info);
                    }else{
                        arg0.getIn().setBody(new ArrayList<Table2>());
                    }

                }
            })
            .to("jpa:Table2?entityType=java.util.ArrayList");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an approach much like how real-time auditing works with Envers.

What you do is register various `PostXXXEventListener` implementations to suit your needs and then have those listeners persist new entities based on the current action being processed.

Take a look inside `org.hibernate.event.spi` for details.