# How to write data into another table after @PostUpdate action using Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Please note that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259733/how-to-write-data-into-table-after-hibernate-entitylistener-action-using-camel) asked, but the answer includes `Camel JPA` specific implementation.

I have a two JPA entities Bo3 and Bo3Audit. In Bo3, there are some fields specified as audit fields. I don't want to take action for all the changes in Bo3, but only for the changes in those fields. When any of those fields' data is inserted (not null) or updated for a particular row, I need to insert an entry in Bo3Audit with the field values.

**Bo3**

```
@Entity // and other JPA annotations
public class Bo3 {
  // persisted fields prop1, prop2, prop3

  // prop1, prop2 are the audit fields
  @Transient@JsonIgnore
  private List<String> myAuditFields = List.of("prop1", "prop2");

  // A supplier which fetches all the getters for the audit fields
  @Transient@JsonIgnore
  Supplier<Stream<Method>> streamSupplier = () -> Arrays.stream(Bo3Audit.class.getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(f -> myAuditFields.contains(f.getName()))
        .map(f->Objects.requireNonNull(
                BeanUtils.findMethod(Bo3Audit.class, "get"+ StringUtils.capitalize(f.getName()))
        ));

}
```

**Bo3Audit**

```
@Entity // and other JPA annotations
public class Bo3Audit {
  // persisted fields prop1, prop2 (only Bo3's audit fields)

  @ManyToOne(lazy fetch)
  private Bo3 bo3;
}
```

**Bo3Audit Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface Bo3AuditRepository extends JpaRepository<Bo3Audit, Long> {
    @Query("from Bo3Audit where bo3.id = :id order by createdAt desc")
    List<Bo3Audit> findLastAudit(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**PrePersist**

The `prePersist` listener in Bo3 **is working as expected**. If either prop1 or prop2 has a non null value, it inserts a row in Bo3Audit copying those values.

```
  @PrePersist
  public void prePersist() {
    Bo3Audit bo3Audit = generateAudit(this); // copies prop1, prop2 and assign "this" to ManyToOne field bo3
    streamSupplier.get().map(m-> {
                try {
                    return m.invoke(bo3Audit);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findAny().ifPresent(value -> {
                MyBeanUtils.getBean(Bo3AuditRepository.class).save(bo3Audit);
            });
  }
```

**PostUpdate**

But the `postUpdate` listener **is failing** with `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
@PostUpdate
public void postUpdate() {
    Bo3AuditRepository repo = MyBeanUtils.getBean(Bo3AuditRepository.class);
    Bo3Audit bo3Audit = generateAudit(this); // copies prop1, prop2 and assign "this" to ManyToOne field bo3
    List<Bo3Audit> lastAudits = repo.findLastAudit(this.getId(), PageRequest.of(0,1));
    ///
    // Some logic using streamSupplier to check any one of the "prop1" and "prop2" value is changed.
    ///
    if (isChanged) {
        repo.save(bo3Audit);
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- If `@PreUpdate` is used, a `StackOverFlow` error is throw somewhere around line `repo.findLastAudit(this.getId(), PageRequest.of(0,1));`
- If the @PostUpdate listener annotation is removed and call the `postUpdate` method from business logic just after `bo3Repository.save(newBo3)` command, this is working fine. An audit
  row is inserted if there is change in either "prop1" or "prop2".

But I need the listener to work. Please suggest.

**Some stack trace**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1054)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:602)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.paanini.generated.app.jiffy.controller.defaultInternalServiceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cff4506b.UpdateBo3(<generated>)
```

Comment: Can you maybe include the `Bo3AuditRepository ` class in your question?

Comment: Does the error also occur when removing the `repo.save(bo3Audit);` in the `@PostUpdate`?

Comment: yes @dan1stisonstrike. Commenting out `repo.save(bo3Audit);` still produces the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prePersist` is working, but not the `postUpdate`. So I had a look at the stack trace again and noted that it was complaining about concurrent modification on some List. The only list in that method is `List<Bo3Audit> lastAudits` which I fetch to compare old and new audit specific fields.

This was the culprit. In the Hibernate perspective, the newly created `bo3Audit` is a member of that list and calling `save` on `bo3Audit` would throw the concurrent modification error.

I did the below updates to the code and it is working as expected.

1. When the Bo3 is loaded, the corresponding Bo3Audit is generated and
   cached to a transient property in Bo3. The hibernate will load the data before updating. So this will work in `@PostUpdate`.

   ```
   @Transient@JsonIgnore private Bo3Audit lastBo3Audit;
   @PostLoad
   public void postLoad() {
       this.lastBo3Audit = this.generateAuditBo();
   }
   ```
2. In `@PostUpdate`, the `oldValues` were generated from this cached
   property, instead of fetching this from database.

   ```
   oldValues = streamSupplier.get().map(m-> {
                   try {
                       return m.invoke(lastBo3Audit);
                   } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                       throw new RuntimeException(e);
                   }
               })
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .toList();
   ```

The queries generated:

```
Hibernate: select bo3x0_.id as id1_0_0_, bo3x0_.prop1 as prop2_0_0_, bo3x0_.prop2 as prop3_0_0_, bo3x0_.prop3 as prop4_0_0_ from bo3 bo3x0_ where bo3x0_.id=?
Hibernate: update bo3 set prop1=?, prop2=?, prop3=? where id=?
Hibernate: insert into bo3audit (bo3_id, prop1, prop2) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Notes:

1. Now that I have the `lastBo3Audit`, the `streamSupplier` can be
   removed and compare `lastBo3Audit` and new `bo3Audit`.
2. I need to test this, to see how it will behave in a real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trivial reason why that does not work as expected: Hibernate fires JPA Lifecycle Events when persistent context is being flushing and you may not modify (write to) persistent context when it is being flushing, however some workarounds do exist:

I. Use brand new persistent context attached to the current transaction, something like:

```java
// suppose we may somehow access EntityManager instance:
Session current = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
try (Session newSession = current.sessionWithOptions().connection().flushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL).openSession()) {
   Bo3Audit bo3Audit = generateAudit...;
   newSession.persist(bo3Audit);
   newSession.flush();
}
```

the code above is robust as AK 47, however has obvious drawbacks:

- it is tightly coupled with Hibernate
- you may not use `spring-data-java` infrastructure

II. another option is to use [Domain Events](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-domain-event/) - please check carefully drawbacks described in article, the most serious one is a requirement to call `save` or `saveAll` in order to trigger `Domain Events`

Comment: Thanks @andrey. Let me try out these and come back.

Comment: I checked your first solution, but it was still throwing the error. Before trying the second I had a look at the stack trace again and noted something. Made some changes in the code as explained in my answer and got it working. Thanks for the support Andrey.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to rework architect? Create new logic layer, that invoke method (for example, let's name it someMethodA(). It can be Service(logic layer above the repository of first entity) method. And you get result. And after this, you invoke another method of another service(with repository of another entity)
You can use pattern Action for this.
Because what you have written is a very dirty architecture, as i think

Comment: Thanks @EvoMGenius for your suggestion. Our current implementation is same as you suggested. The service layer saves `Bo3` through its repository interface `Bo3Repository`, generates `Bo3Audit` and saves it by calling `Bo3AuditRepository` method. But a the new requirement came where the `Bo3` insert or update can be done from multiple places(multiple service methods) and for that, we have to call `someMethodA` from all those places. The ask is to avoid this and use event listeners instead. So I have to stick with this unless we get a better solution using event listeners.